# <Link> not transmitted in children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I work on a dashboard project at my job and I'm need your help.
React, nextjs and material-ui are used in my application.
On this website, a Menu is defined with clickable links for navigate between page.

However, I can not use correctly `<Link>` from `next/link`.

In my application, I need to use `<Link/>` with something like that:

```
import Foo from './foo';
[...]
<Link href="/about" passHref>
  <Foo />
</Link>
[...]
```

`<Foo/>` is defined in another file and contain a `<a>`.
Even if I pass passHref my link can't be clicked.

In real life, my application is more complicated and use material-ui but the problem seems to be present with this really simplified version : https://gist.github.com/Oyabi/4aea0ce2fa36029868641d147ba9e551

Here the code if gist is down or removed in future:

*pages/index.jsx:*

```
import React from "react";
import Menu from "../components/Menu";

function Home() {
  return <Menu />;
}

export default Home;
```

*components/Menu.jsx:*

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";

function Menu() {
  return (
    <Link href="/about" passHref>
      <MenuItem />
    </Link>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

*components/MenuItem.jsx:*

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

function MenuItem() {
  return (
    <div>
      <a>not ok - link is not clickable even if the following lines are commented</a>

      <br />

      <Link href="/about" passHref>
        <a>ok - link is clickable</a>
      </Link>

      <Link href="/about" passHref>

        <a>ok - link is clickable</a>
      </Link>

      <Link href="/about" passHref>
        <div className="useless">
          foo
          <a>even with something more complicated</a>
          <br />
          <a>the 2 links are clikable</a>
          bar
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MenuItem;
```

If I surround my `<a>` between `<Link>` in the same file everything is ok and work as desired but it's not the case if I apply `<Link>` on a component.
As you can see, even if I set`passHref`.

How can I make my `<Link>` works in `Menu.jsx`?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the surrounding `div` by a `fragment` like that:

```
function MenuItem() {
  return (
    <> // here
      <a>not ok - link is not clickable even if the following lines are commented</a>

      <br />

      <Link href="/about" passHref>
        <a>ok - link is clickable</a>
      </Link>

      <Link href="/about" passHref>

        <a>ok - link is clickable</a>
      </Link>

      <Link href="/about" passHref>
        <div className="useless">
          foo
          <a>even with something more complicated</a>
          <br />
          <a>the 2 links are clikable</a>
          bar
        </div>
      </Link>
    </> // and here
  );
}
```